# How to add items in bunifudropdown control

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

How do you add items like for example in a combobox we use this code

```
//this is the code for combobox
If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "A" Then
    ComboBox2.Items.Add("101") 
    ComboBox2.Items.Add("102")
Else
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "B" Then
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("201")
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("202")            
    End If
End If

//this is the code i tried
If BunifuDropdown1.selectedValue = "A" Then
    BunifuDropdown2.Items.add("101")
    BunifuDropdown2.Items.add("102")
Else
    If BunifuDropdown1.selectedValue = "B" Then
        BunifuDropdown2.Items.add("201")
        BunifuDropdown2.Items.add("202")
    End If
End If
```

I need a code like this for BunifuDropdown1
please help!

Comment: What did you try before asking for code?

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: Ok thanks, and with the code you tried what didn't work?

Comment: it contains errors so it cannot run
the error is
'add' is not a member of 'sting()'